# How to access return data of jQuery.ajax() sent to php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using the following jquery ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    submitAct();

function submitAct(){
    var alldata = [];
    alldata.push( {
        "pid": 'd2a7d886-6821-3eaa-079f-fbe278c6a16a',
        "title": 'Fun with Gophers',
    });

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        type: 'POST',
        url: '//[server path]/act',
        data: "data=" + JSON.stringify(alldata),
    });
}
});
```

On the server, the result of $_POST[data] is showing as:

```
[{"pid":"d2a7d886-6821-3eaa-079f-fbe278c6a16a","title":"Fun with Gophers"}]
```

I am having trouble accessing the keys and related values of 'pid' and 'title'. Would someone please provide some insight? I've tried things like below but haven't had any success:

```
$_POST['title']

$data = json_decode( $_POST['data']);
$data->title
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($data)`?

Comment: var_dump($data) is empty. Could it be losing values in the json_decode method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several suggestions:

First you are enclosing the data object in an array, needlessly. To access it now:

```
$data = json_decode( $_POST['data']);
$data=$data[0];/* access object in array*/
$data->title;
```

The default content type for $.ajax  is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`...exactly the same as sending a regular form. Think of each key in your data object as you would `name` of a form control.

There is no need to JSON.stringify to send. jQuery will serialize objects and arrays for you

You can simply send it like this:

```
var alldata = {
    "pid": 'd2a7d886-6821-3eaa-079f-fbe278c6a16a',
    "title": 'Fun with Gophers',
};
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: 'POST',
    url: '//[server path]/act',
    data: alldata 
});
```

Then in php:

```
$title=$_POST['title'];
```

Comment: Yes, much simpler :) Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `data` part of the ajax request to the following:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: 'POST',
    url: '//[server path]/act',
    data: {"data": JSON.stringify(alldata)},
});
```

Now you can access the sent content via `$_POST["data"]` in the appropriate php file.

Example:

```
$json = json_decode($_POST["data"]);
var_dump($json[0]->{"title"}); // [0] because of the array
```

Comment: Thanks. That is giving a blank value. It has a value while in the &_POST variable, but maybe is losing it after the json_decode?

Comment: @user2977016 change the `data` part of your ajax request to the one in my updated answer and try the given example

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = json_decode($_POST['data']);
print_r($a[0]->pid);
```